# how to pass two variables from database to display into an array in android

Tags: java, android

i am new to android programming, i am getting values from database into two variables like below

```
[
  {
    "user": "varun",
    "message": "hello word, my first message "
  },
  {
    "user": "varun",
    "message": "hello word, my first message "
  },
  {
    "user": "rahul",
    "message": "hello world"
  },
  {
    "user": "rahul",
    "message": "world: its cool"
  },
  {
    "user": "rahul",
    "message": "awesom"
  },
  {
    "user": "rahul",
    "message": "ranom"
  },
  {
    "user": "rahul",
    "message": "randimagain"
  },
```

and also to display them in my ListView, am using an array to add them and display.

code:

```
final String TAG = events.class.getSimpleName();
                Log.d(TAG, "showJSON: \n" + jsonArray);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        items.add(jsonObject.getString("user"));
                        items.add(jsonObject.getString("message"));


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

but this way what is happening, first it is creating username child view and then my message child view. is there any way i can display first JSON data into one child view of a ListView like username and followed by message.
i am looking for an option as a one ListView for first user and message and soon.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your items object is an array, you should make an object (Message) with 2 fields : User (String) and Message (String).

Then instead of

```
items.add(jsonObject.getString("user"));
items.add(jsonObject.getString("message"));
```

use an array of Messages(or a list) : Message[] messages = new...

```
messages[i].setUser(jsonObject.getString("user"));
messages[i].setMessage(jsonObject.getString("message"));
```

This will allow you to get each object and field with a getter.

```
messages.[i].getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `user`(String) and `message`(String) to the `items` list as a single String object :

`String item = jsonObject.getString("user") + "\n" + jsonObject.getString("message")`
`items.add(item);`

You could format the `item` string the way you want.